# Make grid add new columns as needed

Tags: html, css, css-grid

The grid should have 2 columns and 5 rows in. The 1st column has a width of `1fr` and the 2nd column has a width of `120px`. If there are more than 5 items in the 2nd column as there are in the image below, another column `120px` wide should be formed next to the existing `120px` wide column.

This is my grid at the moment:

[image: imgur link]

And this is my code:

```css
#media {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 120px;
  grid-auto-rows: 110px;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
}

#main {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 6 / 2;
}

.side-item {
  width: 100%;
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
}

.side-item img {
  height: 80px;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: var(--primary);
  object-fit: cover;
}

.side-item p {
  width: 120px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#main {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#main img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--primary);
  object-fit: cover;
}

#main p {
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div id="media">
  <div id="main">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" alt="">
    <p><i>Option 1</i></p>
  </div>
  <div class="side-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" alt="">
    <p><i>Option 1</i></p>
  </div>
  <div class="side-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" alt="">
    <p><i>Option 2</i></p>
  </div>
  <div class="side-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" alt="">
    <p><i>Option 3</i></p>
  </div>
  <div class="side-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" alt="">
    <p><i>Option 4</i></p>
  </div>
  <div class="side-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" alt="">
    <p><i>Option 5</i></p>
  </div>
  <div class="side-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" alt="">
    <p><i>Option 6</i></p>
  </div>
  <div class="side-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" alt="">
    <p><i>Option 7</i></p>
  </div>
  <div class="side-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" alt="">
    <p><i>Option 8</i></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I accomplish this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key element missing from your code is [`grid-auto-flow: column`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow).

You need a vertical flow of grid items. The default setting is `grid-auto-flow: row`, which lays them out horizontally.

Make these adjustments to your code:

```
#media {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-columns: 120px;
  grid-auto-rows: 110px;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.side-item {
  /* width: 100%; */
  /* grid-column: 2 / span 1; */
}
```

```css
#media {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-columns: 120px;
  grid-auto-rows: 110px;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-auto-flow: column; /* new */
}


#main {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 6 / 2;
}

.side-item img {
  height: 80px;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: var(--primary);
  object-fit: cover;
}

.side-item p {
  width: 120px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#main img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--primary);
  object-fit: cover;
}

#main p {
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div id="media">
  <div id="main">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" alt="">
    <p><i>Option 1</i></p>
  </div>
  <div class="side-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" alt="">
    <p><i>Option 1</i></p>
  </div>
  <div class="side-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" alt="">
    <p><i>Option 2</i></p>
  </div>
  <div class="side-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" alt="">
    <p><i>Option 3</i></p>
  </div>
  <div class="side-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" alt="">
    <p><i>Option 4</i></p>
  </div>
  <div class="side-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" alt="">
    <p><i>Option 5</i></p>
  </div>
  <div class="side-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" alt="">
    <p><i>Option 6</i></p>
  </div>
  <div class="side-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" alt="">
    <p><i>Option 7</i></p>
  </div>
  <div class="side-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" alt="">
    <p><i>Option 8</i></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d4g6cnwf/1/)